# MYSQL database performance

Tags: mysql, database-design

Is it wrong to create PivotTables for each new client in my mysql database? For each table will be a large number of data, and I think I get more organized if each client has their own tables, which in this case is 10 for each new client. But in performance? Would that affect? Would it be more advantageous just one table for everyone? Remembering that if it were only one would be a very large number of lines, about 1 million, for example. And then? Could anyone tell me the real difference in performance in this case?

The hosting machine, according to the provider, has these settings:

- The motherboard of the server where your site is hosted is SuperMicro.
- Using 4 x Intel (R) Xeon (R) CPU E5-2630 processors
- And with dedicated SSD HDDs for your application.

Comment: What do you mean by "bank"?  A financial site?

Comment: @RickJames sorry, it would be a database, my english is not very good: /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you are talking about is big, of course having a different table for each customer will make your queries faster, because both data and indexes will be smaller. And - assuming that you use `innodb_file_per_table=1` - you will have other advantages concerning operations, for example if one table gets corrupted InnoDB will need to repair a smaller quantity of data.

Another solution, probably a bit cleaner, is using partitioning. You can physically partition a table into more files, so the effect is the same: the portion of data and indexes you query will be smaller. You can partition by customer id. Some advantages are:

- Applications will use the customer id in the query's WHERE clause, which is much more standard than putting it in the table name.
- A single ALTER TABLE will affect all customers - most probably this is good when adding columns, for sure it is good when adding indexes.
- Deleting data of a specific customer would be easy and fast.
- Should you need to run multi-customers queries, you will be able to do it easily.

Disadvantages can depend on your specific use case. For example, I cannot know if, for some obscure reason, you want to be able to add a column only for a set of customers.

The only "standard" disadvantage that I have on the top of my mind is that you won't be able to store some partitions on a different media. But there are reasons not to do that (for example, backups manageability).

Also, MySQL never parallelise queries - so, in this respect, there is no difference between using partitioning or using separate tables.

Comment: In case of 1000 tables, for example, could it cause any problems?

Comment: Also, thank you, you have given me a light here.

Comment: Partitioning? No. Just be sure to use a good partitioning expression - a single INT columns would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the other answer.

Thousands of tables leads to thousands of files, overhead in accessing different files for different users, extra disk space used for the internal overhead, etc.

Hundreds of `PARTITIONs` in a single table has the same problems.

In both cases, performance in *not* inherently improved.  The cost of picking the table (or partition) is comparable to any savings.  Your code needs to be more complex to pick the table to use; so you should consider having one `DATABASE` per "user", a la WordPress.  The issues with having hundreds of databases are similar to having lots of tables.

This site has lots of questions like "Is it better to have one-table-per-thingie, or a single table."  The answer is again and again a resounding *one table*.  I won't repeat the arguments here.